# Logging MDBs and Webservice

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j, weblogic

I have an Ear file which consist in 2 jars (mdbs) and a war (webservice) deployed on weblogic.
Where I shoul put

DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml"); ?

I read a method of configuring on web xml a servlet just for initializing the logger but i don,t feel confortable creTing a servlet just for that.

In the webservice constructor again is not ok cause the ws migt be instantiated more then once...(it's up to container to instantiate as many ws )

In Mdbs i do not know where to initialize logs.

Shoul i create singleton which method is called only once? (looks ugly but it shoul work)

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Mdb should have an "init()" method, as servlet does. You may superclass the fwk servlet that does ws, and overload its init. IMHO, I would intialize in both the three artefacts separately, it enforces independency.

Comment: I found a way for the WS ... define a servlet listener in web.xml and i put it there.